# Replacement for Nest.Dsl.Factory in NEST 1.x

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We used Nest.Dsl.Factory add-on to NEST library with earlier versions of NEST. Now that it's approaching version 1, it looks that Nest.Dsl.Factory is no longer supported. I wonder if NEST has now similar functionality built into the core package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DSL Factory DSL has indeed been dropped, after it was donated it became unmaintained.

See the release notes for `0.11.7.0`

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/releases/tag/0.11.7.0

You should now switch to the fluent lambda syntax or use the new object initializer syntax.

Fluent syntax:

- http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/core/search.html
- http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/writing-queries.html

Example initializer syntax:

- [See this unit test](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/dc2790ffaabceea884fd2a80189995abea390253/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Search/InitializerSyntax/InitializerExample.cs#L20)

The object initializer syntax is something we are rolling out for all the API endpoints for the 1.0 release but is currently only available in our continuous builds on myget.org

https://www.myget.org/gallery/elasticsearch-net

Comment: I see. This is why I found it in GitHub sources and was wondering why it's not available in NuGet package. I will get the newer package from MyGet.org, thanks.